How to change the spacing between NSTextList marker and text in UITextView?
I’m working with NSTextList in a UITextView, and I need to change the spacing between the list marker (“1.” or a bullet) and the text itself. However, setting any of parameters in NSMutableParagraphStyle doesn’t seem to affect the marker’s spacing at all.
I have tried setting both firstLineHeadIndent and headIndent in NSMutableParagraphStyle to adjust the spacing, but neither works. I expect these properties to increase the space between the list marker and the text, but the spacing remains the same.
I’m wondering if this behavior is fixed for NSTextList, or if there is another way to change the spacing.
let textList = NSTextList(markerFormat: .decimal, options: 0)

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.textLists = [textList]
paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 10 // Doesn't change anything
paragraphStyle.headIndent = 10 // Doesn't change anything

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "A\nB\nC", attributes:
                                                [.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle])

let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 300, height: 500))
textView.attributedText = attributedString

